# generate .o files from compiler instead of .obj files

Tags: cmake, wind-river-workbench

I am working in an embedded project.
target : ppc
compiler : windriver
Host environment : windows 10
build generator : cmake, MinGW makefiles

during compilation i see .c.obj getting generated.
I want .o instead of .c.obj.
How to do this?
am I have to enable any flags for it ?

Comment: `CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION`?

Comment: I added set(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION .o) below project(). but still no improvement.

Comment: "I want .o instead of .c.obj" - Do you want to replace extension `.obj` with `.o`? The extension is chosen in the toolchain for your compiler. As for "double extension", `.c.obj` instead of `.obj`, then this is a generator-specific thing. Double extension is used for separate object files created, e.g., from `main.c` and `main.cpp` files.

Comment: yes, i want the extension .o instead of .c.obj. @Tsyvarev.       anyone please let me know how to specify this in the toolchain file.

Comment: As I noted in my previous comment, you CANNOT get rid of `.c` part of the extension. You MAY, however, replace `.c.obj` with `.c.o`: setting the variable `CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION` to `.o` has exactly that purpose. If that doesn't work for you, then show (add to the question post) **your code** (in form of [mcve]) and describe your exact observations which deviates from the expected ones.